# Set alpha on ImageView without setAlpha

Tags: android, imageview, alpha

Can I programatically set the alpha of an ImageView without the need for being dependent on API level 11 where setAlpha was introduced?

Comment: Ohh.. there is a setAlpha(int alpha) as well in ImageView thats working from API level 1 :)

Answer (score 40):

[ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) has a method [setAlpha(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29) since API leve 1. So you can use it in any API level.
It is the [setAlpha(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29) method of [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) which is introduced in API level 11.

Comment: Use `setImageAlpha(X)` for SDK version >=16!

Comment: I think the last comment is much more useful.

Comment: setAlpha(int) is deprecated.

Comment: It can't be the right answer, because it was asking for a way without setAlpha(), so f.e. with pure XML

Answer (score 4):

I used code to setAlpha of the image itself, not the view. This is available from API level 1..

```
public void toggleButton(int i) {
    if (indImageBtnEnabled[i]) {

        int di = getDrawableId(findViewById(myImagebtns[i]));
        Drawable d = this.getResources().getDrawable(di);
        d.setAlpha(25);

        ((ImageView) findViewById(myImagebtns[i])).setImageDrawable(d);

        indImageBtnEnabled[i] = false;
    } else {
        // findViewById(myImagebtns[i]).setAlpha(1f) << NEEDS API11;
        int di = getDrawableId(findViewById(myImagebtns[i]));
        Drawable d = this.getResources().getDrawable(di);
        d.setAlpha(255);

        ((ImageView) findViewById(myImagebtns[i])).setImageDrawable(d);

        indImageBtnEnabled[i] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think (But don't know for sure) that you could apply an alpha animation to your ImageView, and as long as the fillAfter() is set to true on the animation the Image should stay at whatever alpha level it ends at.

Comment: I just found out the simpler answer :) ... see above.

Comment: that is definitely the way to go then

Answer (score 2):

you can make a new layout with just ur image, set the alpha you need for the layout, set it as an overlay and inflate when you want.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View overView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myAlpahImageLayout, null);
        this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```